# Python Flask Session not working when using custom domain

Tags: python, flask, dns

I hope I am not beginning a thread already in existence, I've browsed quite a few question and none fully resolved my issue. So, my issue is, I have set up a webserver in a Digital Ocean droplet and after I bought a Only Domains custom domain and linked it to the server. When access the IP of the droplet server it works fine, and, apparently it also works when accessing the custom domain name. However, all `session` related features do not worked properly, meaning that all the functionalities I associated to the user login are not working properly on the custom domain access (although they work fine in the original IP access). The code is quite extense and I do not know which part would be beneficial to add, but here it goes:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, \
                    request, session, redirect, \
                    url_for, g
username = ""
user = model.check_users()

@app.route("/", methods = ["GET","POST"])
def home():
    if "username" in session:
        g.user=session["username"]
```

This is an adapted chunk of the code, meaning that all operations involving `g.user` are not recognized at the custom domain. After what I've read, this is most likely related to cookies, but that is way out of my comfort zone, any chance there is a kind soul that could help me?

Comment: It could be the cookies although you are not saying exactly what is not working. Review your Flask config and check options such as SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN or SERVER_NAME perhaps. It is normal practice to have a profile for local development with DEBUG enabled etc, and another profile for a production environment. There has to be some minimal configuration somewhere.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the time it took me to answer, I solved it outside of python by properly setting up a nginx-based server that pointed towards de custom domain I bought, in which case, I needed to configure the appropriate files, but it turned out to be much simpler than going around the cookies. Thanks for your attention, in the case someone runs into the same problem as me, this tutorial worked perfectly: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uswgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04